# Why my code without errors isn't running?

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I need some help! This is my code. When i press run it isn't do anything.
I've tried to install again all the modules, but no luck.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pyttsx3
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


#Intializing Window
window = Tk('500x350')
window.geometry()
window.config(bg='#6C969D')
window.title("Pdf to Audio Speecch |Nick S")

#Labels
startingpagenumber = Entry(window)
startingpagenumber.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.1)
page1 = Label(window,text="Enter starting page number")
page1.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.1)
label = Label(window, text="Select a book.")
label.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)


def file():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    book = open(path, 'rb')
    pdfreader = PdfFileReader(book)
    pages = pdfreader.numPages
    speaker = pyttsx3.init()
    
    for i in range(int(startingpagenumber.get()), pages):
        page = pdfreader.getPage(i) 
        txt = page.extractText()
        speaker.say(txt)
        speaker.runAndWait()
 

B = Button(window, text="Choose  the Book", command=file)
B.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.3)
```

This is what I get in console
`C:\Users\nicks\Desktop\Coding Projects\Python\Pdf to Audio>C:/Users/nicks/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe "c:/Users/nicks/Desktop/Coding Projects/Python/Pdf to Audio/main.py"`

Comment: you never call `mainloop`. add `window.mainloop()` at the end of code. don't use `*` when importing, import what you need or import the module as a whole

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

The problem was that I didn't include `mainloop()` in the end!

Comment: not just `mainloop()`, you ought to use it as a method (e.g., `window.mainloop()`)